GPIO pin usage in Odroid M1, Ver : Android 11
I am developing an app using Odroid M1, android version 11. I want to configure the GPIO pins for application specific usage. I tried AndroidThings, unable to succeed. I checked the dependencies are correct and other related libraries are also fine.
 private fun setupGPIO() {
        try {
            val peripheralManager = PeripheralManager.getInstance()

//             Get and log the list of available GPIOs
            val gpioList = peripheralManager.gpioList
            if (gpioList.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "No GPIO pins available on this device.")
            } else {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "List of available GPIO pins: $gpioList")
            }

            // Setup specific GPIO pins
            buttonF1Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio("gpio120")
            buttonF2Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio("gpio118")
            buttonF3Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio("gpio119")
            buttonF4Gpio = peripheralManager.openGpio("gpio121")

            setupButton(buttonF1Gpio) { scrollCardsForward() }
            setupButton(buttonF2Gpio) { scrollCardsBackward() }
            setupButton(buttonF3Gpio) { activateCard() }
            setupButton(buttonF4Gpio) { onBackPressed() }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error setting up GPIO: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    private fun setupButton(gpio: Gpio, onPressed: () -> Unit) {
        gpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_IN)
        gpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_LOW)
        gpio.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_FALLING)
        gpio.setValue(true) // Enable pull-up

        gpio.registerGpioCallback {
            onPressed()
            true
        }
    }

Can anybody look what the matter is about. Thanks and Reagrds
Trying for configuring the GPIO pins in in Odroid M1 device with Android 11 OS for application specific usage.
